# After adding UIDatePicker, it prints error

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uidatepicker

```
import UIKit

class AddPartyViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate
{
    @IBOutlet weak var textName: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var textAddress: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var textDate: UITextField!

    var date:NSDate?
    var datePickerView: UIDatePicker?

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        datePicker()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func buttonAddParty_Click(sender: UIButton)
    { 
        party.addParty(name: textName.text!, address:textAddress.text!)

        self.view.endEditing(true)

        textName.text = ""
        textAddress.text = ""
    }

    func datePicker()
    {
        datePickerView = UIDatePicker()
        datePickerView?.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.date
        datePickerView?.addTarget(self, action: Selector("handlePickerView:"), for: .valueChanged)

        textDate.inputView = datePickerView
    }

    func handlePickerView(sender: UIDatePicker)
    {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM dd, yyy"
        date = sender.date as NSDate?
        textDate.text = dateFormatter.string(from: sender.date)
    }
}
```

Above is Adding todo list code and below is tableview code

```
import UIKit

class PartiesTableViewController: UIViewController,    UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource
{
    @IBOutlet var tblLists: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    //returning to view
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)
    {
        tblLists.reloadData()
    }

    //UITableViewDataSource
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return party.lists.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "test")

        cell.textLabel?.text = party.lists[indexPath.row].name
        //cell.textLabel?.text = party.lists[indexPath.row].date
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = party.lists[indexPath.row].address

        return cell
    }

    //UITableViewDelegate - delete
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
        if(editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete)
        {
            party.lists.remove(at: indexPath.row)

            tblLists.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

I am working on todo list with Swift 3. What I am trying to do is to add name, address, and date by entering in the textField in AddPartyViewController. name and address are strings, but date is date from UIDatePicker. But the problem is when I click date selection and choose a date in a UIDatePicker on simulator, it gives this error:

> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Can someone help me to solve this issue? Please ask me any questions

Comment: did you set frame of your datepicker ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code `datePicker()` method Have selector problem which this

```
datePickerView?.addTarget(self, action: Selector("handlePickerView:"), for: .valueChanged)
```

Remove above line and replace this line

```
datePickerView?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(AddPartyViewController.handlePickerView(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)
```

I hope this will help you

Comment: what is BViewController??

Comment: sorry for mistake it is AddPartyViewController

Comment: Have you check that?

Comment: oh my goodness....... it works!! thank you !! I really appreciate it :)